# How to make a <div> width dynamic and take any value between its min-width and max-width?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Is there a way to make `<div>` be responsive and take the continuous range of values between its min-width and max-width as the screen size is changed?

A sample of my current HTML structure is below and in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cwdomg8n/68/) playground. The end goal is to make the width of the `<div>` with the blue background slowly decrease from its max-width to its min-width as the screen size is reduced.

HTML

```
<div class="bar-container">
  <div class="left-bar">
    <div class="grey"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-bar">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="red"></div>
      <div class="blue"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="yellow"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.bar-container {
  background-color: black;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.left-bar {
  display: flex;
}

.right-bar {
  display: flex;
}

.grey {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: grey;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.red {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  min-width: 100px;
  max-width: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}

.yellow {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several hours spent on this, I have managed to find a solution. I was focusing too much on the `blue` `<div>` itself, I did not pay attention to the overall HTML structure.
To obtain the desired behaviour,the `right-bar` `<div>` could be made to occupy the whole space until it reaches the `left-bar` `<div>` by setting its `width` to `100%`. The children elements can be aligned to the right. Same for the `wrapper` `<div>`. The `blue` `<div>` is assigned a `width` of `100%`, `min-width` of `100px` and max-width of `200px`.

The final CSS is something like below and the HTML is unchanged.

```
.bar-container {
  background-color: black;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.left-bar {
  display: flex;
}

.right-bar {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.grey {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: grey;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.red {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  max-width: 200px;
  min-width: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}

.yellow {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want the blue div to fill up the entire screen for displays smaller than 768px and gradually go narrower as the screen size is shrunk. You can accomplish this by setting the width property's transition effect to 1 and utilizing the flex-grow: 1 style.
Then add wrapper div to occupy all available space and the blue div to have a set width of 200px for screens 768px and larger. For the blue div, we set flex-grow: 0 and width: 200px, and for the wrapper div, we set flex-grow: 1 and add a padding-right transition effect.

In order for the wrapper div to occupy all available space, we additionally add a:after pseudo-element to the wrapper div with a huge flex-grow value and a padding-right value equal to the width of the yellow div. We also make the right bar div shrinkable. This frees up space so that the yellow div may be seen.
In order to prevent the yellow div from changing size, we add it last and give it a constant width of 100px. We also set its flex-grow and flex-shrink values to 0.

```
/* Media query for screens smaller than 768px */
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .blue {
    flex-grow: 1; /* Take up all available space */
    transition: width 0.5s ease-out; /* Add transition effect */
  }
}

/* Media query for screens 768px and larger */
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .blue {
    flex-grow: 0; /* Don't grow or shrink */
    width: 200px; /* Set width to max-width */
  }
  
  .wrapper {
    flex-grow: 1; /* Take up all available space */
    transition: padding-right 0.5s ease-out; /* Add transition effect */
  }
  
  /* Make the right bar flex item shrinkable */
  .right-bar {
    flex-shrink: 1;
  }
  
  /* Add some padding to the right of the wrapper to make space for the yellow bar */
  .wrapper:after {
    content: '';
    flex-grow: 9999;
    padding-right: 100px; /* Width of the yellow bar */
  }
  
  /* Add the yellow bar */
  .yellow {
    flex-grow: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: yellow;
  }
}
```

Comment: This does not solve the issue. The main point is that I want the width of the blue `<div>` to have a continuous range of values between its `min-width` and `max-width` as the screen is resized. In your code snippet, it will have a value of either `200px` or `133.3px` depending on the screen size. The code snippet above also adds an empty region between the blue and yellow `<div>` for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way to do it in CSS.
by using `min-width:800px;` or `max-width:800px;` or you can do it by using Bootstrap Columns, It is a better way to make the best possible responsive divisions of the page

Comment: Are you referring to media queries? Can you expand on how it can help achieve the description in this case? Also, I cannot use Bootstrap. I would need a solution in HTML/CSS, or JavaScript as a last resort.

Comment: That was the only solution then I guess in my opinion as of now but you may refer to other answers as for responsive design, you can refer to BS but if not that then you need the @media queries, I can't help with media queries

Comment: Can you expand on your original answer though? I'm not sure I understand how it could be used to solve this issue.